# Will trading count towards mythical research Catch a Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have to catch a ditto for mythical research, so does trading for one count? Im on 5/8 for my research.

Comment: Going to try this tonight, will answer then

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it will not count.

I just traded a Ditto to someone who has been trying to catch one for that research task, and the task did not complete for her.